# TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() when iterating through files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to iterate two text files. I have two text files one is for 'username' and another is for 'password'.

It works when I use functions with single argument. [here's the code](https://gist.github.com/pravinnath/0db095ba49e488b1c4a413b2d2763ea6) but not when it comes to use 2 or more than 1 argument.

Here's my code:

```
import os
import time
import getpass
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


def Quora_bot():

    username = None
    password = None

    chromedriver  = 'F:\All  Folders\chromedriver\shit.exe'

#Uncomment this block if you don't want images to load(makes the procss a little bit faster)
    '''
    chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images":2}
    chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver, chrome_options=chromeOptions)
    '''

    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
    browser.get("http://www.quora.com")       # Quora home page
    time.sleep(10)

    # Logging into Quora
    form = browser.find_element_by_class_name('regular_login')
    email = form.find_element_by_name("email")
    password = form.find_element_by_name("password")
    button_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@value='Login']")
    email.send_keys(username)
    password.send_keys(password)


with open('newfile.txt') as u:
      for line in u:
        rr = line


with open('password.txt') as p:
     for linee in p:
       pp = linee

Quora_bot()
username = rr
password = pp
```

And I'm getting this error.

```
    F:\Python_Installer\python.exe C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Quora_Bot/westing.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Quora_Bot/westing.py", line 45, in <module>
    Quora_bot()
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Quora_Bot/westing.py", line 32, in Quora_bot
    email.send_keys(username)
  File "F:\Python_Installer\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 348, in send_keys
    {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
  File "F:\Python_Installer\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\utils.py", line 150, in keys_to_typing
    for i in range(len(val)):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You haven't included the code that has the error. Edit your question and include the relevant parts.

Comment: okay I will post full code

Comment: don't override the Python keywords and builtins like `for, object`

Comment: okay I will try

Comment: All I want is iterate two files

Comment: Don't post full code. Post a [mcve]

Comment: Where have u initialized `val` ?

Comment: Using text files.

Comment: You still have not included the piece of code that is displayed in the error message. Without *that*, people *can't answer*.

Comment: As @JimFasarakisHilliard has already told pls post the part of the code that is responsible for this error so that we can help u better.

Comment: To be more specific @PravinNath post the part where you have the code `for i in range(len(val)):` is and also the part where val is defined and assigned later on.

Comment: Sorry guys. I forgot the code. Soon I will post that

Answer (score 0):

So that we do not end up having everything in the comments let me summarize for you

1. Don't overwrite inbuild keyword such as `for` or `object`
2. your `for_game()' function which is (i guess) should reset`letter`and`animal` is not resetting the global variables but only locally. So it is pointless since it does nothing in the end.
3. Assuming you defined `val`somewhere  where we can't see, make sure it is defined as an object which as a `length` attribute like a `string` or `list` ( i guess most/ all iterables have. At the moment it seems like it is `None` so either you defined it as `None`or maybe set it equal to a function wich has no `return` statement.
4. I dont think your `with` statements are working the way you want them either, since you never `read` the content of the file but only keep the object. you need to read it with `content = file.read()`

But again without the necessary code, we can not help you anymore.

Comment: About ur 4th point, even if he doesnt read the file using `read` or `readlines` this will work. If he wants to just print the contents of the file, this should be fine. But if he wants to store it, then it will always store the last line. In that case,as you said he has to use `read`. Just wanted to add this clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you send None-Type object to the input.
At first you called `Quora_bot()` and defined there:

`username = None`
`password = None`

Then you try to send them as keys to the inputs:
`email.send_keys(username)`
`password.send_keys(password)`

And only then you define them:

```
Quora_bot()
username = rr
password = pp
```

So it gives you this error:

```
  for i in range(len(val)):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

I had the same problem because I didn`t define the path to my .env file and my env-variables had None-Type:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import dotenv
import os
import time

dotenv.load_dotenv()

MY_EMAIL = os.getenv('my-email')
MY_PASSWORD = os.getenv('my-password')
LINK = 'https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?f_LF=f_AL&geoId=102257491&keywords=python%20developer&location=London%2C%20England%2C%20United%20Kingdom&redirect=false&position=1&pageNum=0'
service = Service('C://Development/chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

driver.get(LINK)
sigh_in: WebElement = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'nav__button-secondary')
sigh_in.click()
time.sleep(5)
username_input: WebElement = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'username')
username_input.click()

username_input.send_keys(MY_EMAIL)
password_input: WebElement = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'password')
password_input.send_keys(MY_PASSWORD)
sigh_in: WebElement = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn__primary--large')
sigh_in.click()
```

Output:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/T3600/Desktop/PycharmProjects/job-applying/main.py", line 25, in <module>
    username_input.send_keys(MY_EMAIL)
  File "C:\Users\T3600\Desktop\PycharmProjects\job-applying\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 541, in send_keys
    {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
  File "C:\Users\T3600\Desktop\PycharmProjects\job-applying\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\utils.py", line 148, in keys_to_typing
    for i in range(len(val)):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```